# Program terminates with status -1073741510 in middle of for loop assigning input to 2-D array

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a program for some self-study and the book I'm using wants me to make a program that holds monthly sales for 3 years in a 2-D array. The problem is that the process terminates with status -1073741510 the moment I enter the sales for '2018 april'.

I looked for other people who's program terminated with the same status and dividing by zero errors seemed to be the cause, however I cannot see how this program would get a divide by zero error in this assigning loop.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int Years = 3;
const int Months = 12;
int main()
{
    const char *months[Months] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                        "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                        "October", "November", "December"};
    const char *years[Years] = {"2016", "2017", "2018"};
    int sales[Years][Months];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the sales for 2016-2018" << endl;
    for (const char *x : years)
    {
        for (const char *y : months)
        {
            cout << x << " " << y << ": " << endl;
            cin >> sales[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MarekR I'll look into using a debugger some more, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes out of bounds because you're not putting `j` back to `0` when you went through all the months in a year. When you do `i++;`, also do `j = 0;`.

Comment: When I edited the code just now to output the value immediately after entering the input, I suddenly got a very weird output for what should be sales[2][0]. Then noticed it indeed wasn't sales[2][0] as I had intended. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Errors with multidimensional arrays can be a bit tricky because if the indices are wrong, it's possible that the memory address it calculates internally correspondent to a different part of the array, resulting in the wrong place being overwritten while the intended place stays uninitialized.